# Performance degradation migrating the OS on SSD to bigger SSD

Tags: ssd, performance, migration

I'm planning to buy a bigger SSD but soon a question came up to my mind: would my performance fall down after moving the OS on the bigger SSD (like it happens from HDD > SSD without clean install)? In my opinion the answer is 'no' because we're talking about the same type of device, but I wanted to know what do you think about it

**EDIT**
My question is slightly different. My concern is that migrating the OS on a new SSD might affect performances, but sure the new one is better than mine (it's a 850 EVO 500GB vs 840 EVO 120GB)

Comment: possible duplicate of [To what extent is size a factor in SSD performance?](http://superuser.com/questions/59798/to-what-extent-is-size-a-factor-in-ssd-performance)

Comment: No, your relative performance will stay precisely the same. YOU personally will not notice a difference but synthetic benchmarks might show a variation.

Comment: larger SSDs usually offer greater performance over the same model in a smaller size, so if you have a larger, better SSD, it will most certainly be faster